# Get OS Information Correctly in Java or C#

Tags: java, operating-system, registry

I want to get OS name with edition using java or C# as mentioned in below example :

Example : Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise

I have tried below :

1. In java tried `System.getProperty("os.name")`
   => It does not provide OS edition
2. One ways is to get OS name from registry
   Getting "ProductName" from `\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`
3. I also tried SYSTEMINFO command, it provides OS Name. but since it shows output different language. its not possible to check variable name from output.

But I want to find a way other than finding from registry, so that even if in future versions of OS, registry path changes, App should provide correct OS name.

Is there any other reliable way to find OS name with edition ?

Comment: In Java, not really, no... Unless some guy somewhere has developed a native library covering each and every possible situation.

Comment: I realize this isn't much better, but `systeminfo /nh /fo csv` will always (I think) output the OS name as the second comma-separated value.  At least it doesn't depend on a locale-specific header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used below code because I analysed that most probably registry path will not be changed.

```
    private final String STR_OS_NAME_REGISTRY_QUERY = "reg query \"HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\" /v \"ProductName\"";     

    // Get OS name
        objProcessName = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(STR_OS_NAME_REGISTRY_QUERY); 
        objProcessName.waitFor(); 
        objBufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(objProcessName.getInputStream())); 
        lstJavaInfo = new ArrayList<>();

        while ((sLine = objBufferReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            lstJavaInfo.add(sLine);
        }
        objProcessName.waitFor();

        if(lstJavaInfo.size() < 3)
        {
            return "-";
        }

        String[] sarr = lstJavaInfo.get(2).split("\\s+");
        for(int nIndex = 3 ; nIndex < sarr.length ; nIndex++)
        {
            sOSArchitecture = sOSArchitecture + sarr[nIndex] + " ";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the apache commons lang library - OS_ARCH, OS_NAME, OS_VERSION
maybe it retrieves what you need. Below is a link to its javadocs:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils.html

Comment: besides link to resource can you also provide brief annotation what there- just link its not SO style